# Angular Breaking Date and Time

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this code `<ng-template>{{date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a Z'}}</ng-template>` and it will show a long line date and time.  I want to make a break in between data and time by enter `<br />`, but it doesn't work.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to use the date filter two times

Comment: Can you get more details, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can use these pipes:

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mmss' }}        // output is '43:11'
```

This will give you the desired time or date on the correct lines

```
<ng-template>{{date | date}}<br> {{ date | date:'shortTime' }}</ng-template>
```

More info can be found at the docs: [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Thank you very much!  But how can I make an output with 2 lines: first line is date and second line is time?

Comment: @abcidd See my edit, The first part uses just the date filter while the second uses the shortTime filter. Just add a br between them.

Comment: Thank you very much, RJustin !  I need to update something:  The correct form is `<ng-template>{{row.lastupdated | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a Z'}}</ng-template> How to insert a `<br>`?

Comment: <ng-template>{{row.lastupdated | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a Z'}}<br>{{row.lastupdated | date:'shortTime'}}</ng-template>



If this concludes your question please mark as accepted to help others in the future.